# Inserting a 'day' column in Access

Tags: ms-access

I'm working in Access and currently have a column with a time stamp in the format DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm. I'm trying to insert a column next to it that only contains the relevent day in number format without the rest of the timestamp. I'm sure this is painfully simple but for some reason I can't figure it out.

Many thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a query, add the expression:

```
Day([YourTimestampFieldName])
```

In a form with a textbox, use this ControlSource for the textbox:

```
=Day([YourTimestampFieldName])
```

If *relevent day in number format* means something else than the day, please specify.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options.

1. You can design to column to be a specific format in the table design view. This will enforce date formats for you. Its been a minute for me, but I believe it even works as you try to insert into that column.
2. You can use the FORMAT function on inserts, as getting data from another column/data type is what youre doing. its actual specific use is of:

   ```
   FORMAT(yourColumn, "MM-DD-YYYY")
   ```

If you need more specifics, you can google the function.

3. You can set up a macro that will function like a trigger in normal RDMS's. This i envision will UpSert the value to the new column based on INSERT/UPDATE logic.

Let me know if you think this requires more assistance. I think this should be more than enough to get you started.